# Integrate two select queries

Tags: mysql, database, select

I have two queries and I just want make them a single query. If somebody knows help me. Appreciate any help. This is first query:

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS a6 AS SELECT 
u.id,n.rus,u.partiya,s.tip,s.son,s.son_d,s.son_jami,b.code FROM umumiy 
u LEFT` JOIN nomi n on u.id_nomi=n.id LEFT JOIN soni s on u.id=s.u_id 
LEFT JOIN` barcode b on u.id=b.u_id WHERE u.okk=0;
```

And my second query is here:

```
SELECT
    (son_jami - (son_d * son)) as 'dona'
from asosiy
```

Any ideas?

Comment: Do you mean you want to combine the two SELECTs in order to create the table? If so, how are they related?

Comment: Have you tried just running them both? What is your actual issue? Do you get an error or what?

Comment: **Sloan Thrasher.** Yes, I mean it. They are not related. I mean first select query  grasps data from 4 tables and second query just select data from 5th table(which is not related). Final query should create table involving 2 select queries

Comment: There is no any issue. But I'm just trying to make one query from two